# (Updated): Showing that a set $M$ with two elements classifies as a field

Tags: field-theory, self-learning

My question is more conceptual, so I will come straight to the exercise:

> **Exercise**: Let $M= \lbrace g,u \rbrace $ be a Set. On $M$ the Addition and the Multiplication is given by:
>   \begin{align} g+g = u+u &= g \tag{$\alpha$} \\g+u = u+g& = u \tag{ $\beta$} \\  \\  g \cdot g = u \cdot g = g \cdot u & =g \\ u \cdot u & =u \end{align}

I know what it takes for $M$ to be a field, axiom wise. I will just focus on the additive properties, if I got it right there I can also do the multiplicative ones.

**Commutativity**: Follows straight from $\beta$. $\beta \implies g+u = u + g, \ \forall u,g \in M$

**Existence of additive identity**: $\alpha \implies g+g=g \implies g \equiv 0$

**Existence of additive inverses**: $\alpha \implies u + u = g =0 \implies u$ is inverse element of $u$ and I believe it is correct to say that $ \alpha \implies g+g=g =0 \implies g$ is inverse element of $g$

**Associativity**: Here I struggle. The set $M$ only contains two elements, to show associativity I would have (intuitively) said that I need three elements. However, there are Galois Fields which only contain two elements (we didn't address that in Class, I did exhaust google for that)

So I thought about the following 'workaround': Let $c \in M= \lbrace u,g \rbrace \implies c=u \vee c = g$. If $c=u$ we have: $$g+(u+c)=g+(u+u)\overset{\alpha}=g+g=(u+u)+g =(u+c)+g$$
and then the same for $c=g$. Is this (and the above) correct? Or do I need to formulate my thoughts differently?

**Update**: After the answer given below my insight into this problem is better. I know now that for associativity I need to analyze 8 cases. I have written down all those cases, but I am lost for the one if $(x,y,z) \in M^3$ with $(x,y,z)=(u,g,g) $ then I have $$ u+(g+g)\overset{\alpha}=u+(g)\overset{com.}=(g)+u=(g+g)+u=... ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associativity involves three elements, but they do not have to be distinct. So with a two element field $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$ means that whatever values $a,b,c$ take in the field, the equation is true. There are eight possibilities to check, which is not too bad.

Associativity can be a pain to prove if you don't have a short cut. The associativity of the two element field can be established by identifying it with $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and using the associativity of $\mathbb Z$.

Likewise, it is easy to prove that the composition of functions is associative. We can prove that matrix multiplication is associative by associating each matrix with a function (a linear map relative to a basis), rather than computing the matrix entries element by element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you also comment if my steps above were correct for commutativity and existence? For Associativity your answer seems to imply that I have only covered 1/7 possibilities.

Comment: I believe to understand it now. For commutativity I need to pick arbitrary elements two, so for $(x,y) \in M^2$ I would have $4$ possibilities again which I'd have to verify.

Comment: just a quick follow up question, are there really 8 cases? in case that lets say $(x,y,z)=(u,u,u)$ wouldn't that imply that the 'field' I am looking at only consists of one element? I have solved this question long time ago btw, just gave it some additional thought today on my reviews.

Comment: @Spaced Using $0,1$ for the field elements, each of $a,b,c$ can have two possible values i.e. $0$ or $1$. That makes $2^3=8$ possibilities.