# Confusion about the associative property and the mechanics of Parenthesis

Tags: self-learning, definition, associativity

This is a follow up question on my earlier post [(Updated): Showing that a set $M$ with two elements classifies as a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949766/updated-showing-that-a-set-m-with-two-elements-classifies-as-a-field). I feel this post is necessary because I realize that what confuses me is how braces work in rigorous Mathematics. Consider the example below:

> **Example:** Let $M= \lbrace u,g \rbrace $ be a set and the multiplication defined as follows: \begin{align} g \cdot g = u \cdot g = g \cdot u = g \tag{M1} \\ u \cdot u = u \tag{M2} \end{align}

I want to verify that the associative property for the above defined form of multiplication holds, assuming that I have already shown commutativity (which is clear by the definition)

So let $(x,y,z) \in M^3= \lbrace u ,g \rbrace ^2$, there are 8 cases I need to realize,  I will only use two, one which is easy (for me) to show and one that I can only show with some 'magic'.

**Case 1**: Let $(x,y,z)=(u,g,u)$. Then I have: $$u\cdot (g \cdot u) \overset{M1}=u \cdot (g) \overset{com.}=(g) \cdot u \overset{M1}=(u \cdot g)\cdot u $$

Please note that during the whole process I kept my braces ( ) adamantly in place on purpose.

**Case 2**: Let $(x,y,z)=(u,u,g)$. Then I have: $$u\cdot (u \cdot g) \overset{M1}= u \cdot (g) \overset{com}= (g) \cdot u =(u \cdot g ) \cdot u\overset{M1}=(u \cdot u \cdot g) \cdot u \overset{*}=(u\cdot u) \cdot g \cdot u \\ \overset{M1}=(u \cdot u ) \cdot g$$

Where (*) clearly is some magic I cannot explain to myself mathematically, verbally all I did was moving the right ")" brace to the left and voila, but this way there would be no need to even verify the associative property.

Is there a way to show the associative property for Case 2? Are there any rules for placing/moving braces?

Comment: Why make it so long and complicated? In Case 1 what's wrong with just saying $u\cdot(g\cdot u)=u\cdot g=g$ and $(u\cdot g)\cdot u=g\cdot u =g$, or simply $u\cdot(g\cdot u)=u\cdot g=g\cdot u=(u\cdot g)\cdot u$? And in Case 2, what's wrong with just saying that $u\cdot(u\cdot g)=u\cdot g=(u\cdot u)\cdot g$?

Comment: So the mechanics of Parenthesis are that I can drop/ignore them when it comes to a statement like $u\cdot (g)=u \cdot g$ ?

Comment: And what is $(u\cdot u\cdot g)$ supposed to mean anyway? Is it $(u\cdot u)\cdot g$ or is it $u\cdot(u\cdot g)$?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. I don't know about "mechanics of Parenthesis". I'm wondering what you imagine $(g)$ means and how it's different from plain $g$. I guess if you had a problem to calculate $9\cdot(5-3)$ you'd get as far as $9\cdot(5-3)=9\cdot(2)$ and then you'd be stuck, because you know that $9\cdot2=18$ but you don't know what $9\cdot(2)$ is?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @bof $9 \cdot (2)$ would indeed make no sense in arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for each case is to evaluate both sides and check they are equal.

$$u \cdot (u \cdot g) = u \cdot g = g$$
$$(u \cdot u) \cdot g = u \cdot g = g$$

So $u \cdot (u \cdot g) = (u \cdot u) \cdot g$.

Regarding your question in the comments, there is no difference between $u \cdot (g)$ and $u \cdot g$.  Parentheses are only for grouping.  They tell you to evaluate what's inside the parentheses first.  In $u \cdot (g)$ there is nothing to evaluate in $(g)$ so it's the same as $u \cdot g$.